# Tweet text from a Wordpress Div

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull text from a div created by the "Quotes Collection" plugin/widget in Wordpress in order allow users to tweet it out.

I want to autopopulate the text so I have to grab it.

The code for where the text is located:

```
    <div class="quote">
        <div id="quotescollection_randomquote-0" class="quotescollection_randomquote">
          <p><q>QUOTE TEXT HERE!</q> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to get that quote text here out and into a prepopulated tweet.  I'm a real neophyte with PHP and how this integrates - I think the likely solution is with jquery and .text() and then trying to append that into the twitter href?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before start coding you should learn about [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath).

---

In PHP you'll do it using [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Here comes an example:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div class="quote">
  <div id="quotescollection_randomquote-0" class="quotescollection_randomquote">
    <p><q>QUOTE TEXT HERE!</q> </p>
  </div>
</div>
EOF;

// create a document object from your html string
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// create a xpath selector for the document
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// use xpath query to access the text of <q> node
$quote = $selector
  ->query('//div[@class="quote"]/div/p/q/text()')
  ->item(0)
  ->nodeValue;

// output
echo $quote; // Output: QUOTE TEXT HERE!
```

Comment: Thank you - this was a huge help.